# devise_token_auth or devise-token_authenticatable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-api

I am a beginner to Ruby on Rails. Now working on APi with 'rails-api' gem and i succeeded. I want to include authentication and my client in jquery ajax.

When i search about this i got 2 gems which are below

[devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)

[devise-token_authenticatable](https://github.com/baschtl/devise-token_authenticatable)

Please suggest the better one. As per my stage i am not going to write my own token authentication so i need to select the better one and easy to implement so that i can use the api from jquery client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go (and actually did so) with more known/often used/popular gem, which is in this case the first option ([devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)). It has more questions here on SO and lots of opened and closed issues on [github repo](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues), which means any problem you'll face most likely would already be solved.